# Mien dans un mien ami

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Dans l'expression :

**un mien ami**

À quelle classe grammaticale appartient mien et quelle est sa fonction grammaticale ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La tournure est rare et aujourd'hui généralement humoristique. Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mien) décrit cet usage :

> B. − *Adj. qualificatif*
>   1. [En corrélation avec l'art. indéf. ou le dém. et antéposé au subst. (dans des groupes nom. où *mon* (*ma*, *mes*) est exclu parce qu'il est trop proche de *le* et contradictoire avec *un*)]
>   − [Avec un subst. désignant une pers.] *Le caractère de ce mien camarade. À propos, j'ai un mien ami qui veut me faire faire un mariage de deux cent mille livres* (Flaub., *Corresp.*, 1852, p.356). *L'opium dont j'usais avait été acheté par un mien ami* (Baudel., *Paradis artif.*,1860, p.437). *On ne se marie, m'assure une mienne cousine, que...* (Montherl., *Olymp.*,1924, p.245).

Les formes habituelles sont ***un ami à moi*** (registre courant) et ***un de mes amis*** (plus soutenu).